# Application Verifier fails to start on 3 separate Windows machines here

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, application-verifier

Simply, I cannot run App verifier (WOW or 64-bit). It simply does not start. Event viewer says:

Faulting application name: appverif.exe, version: 10.0.18362.1, time stamp: 0x58ca3409
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1139, time stamp: 0x335bbdaf
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000dfa1d
Faulting process ID: 0x2ad0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6aa7ad4a12bf6
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\appverif.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 235c3a4d-2d54-4436-99bf-b54a217c9a7f

Additionally, I tried to run appverif.exe (in system and syswow64) under Visual Studio and I see:

[image: Application Verifier blows up in Visual Studio debugger]

EDIT (Update based on comments)
Some are suggesting that Application Verifier does not have a GUI. However, last time I ran it, I saw the following:

[image: Application Verifier Gui]

Comment: The error code is `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`. Are you sure this is AppVerifier failing as opposed to AopVerifier reporting a bug in your test application?

Comment: Well, since App verifier never even opens its GUI, I have no idea what programs are set to use Application Verifier?! Just to be clear, I am not running any program inside Application Verifier. It is App verifier *itself* that crashes -- on all 3 machines.

Comment: use [gflags.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags-flag-table) to enable appverifier for your target application

Comment: AppVerifier doesn't have a dedicated GUI, but rather communicates issues by way of exceptions that can be intercepted by any Windows debugger. That's its standard mode of operation.

Comment: Hi -- Didn't it used to have a GUI that allowed you to add applications and view logs?

Comment: The image you posted is the configuration UI that ultimately writes to the Image File Execution Options registry key. So yes, there is *some* UI, that even lets you view logs of previous runs. Though that isn't the default mode of the AppVerifier engine. By default, it throws exceptions when it observes an issue. Given how tedious it is to change AppVerifier from throwing exception to logging issues (and how unhelpful the logs are) I indeed forgot that AppVerifier can be run without a debugger. Anyway, now you know where to look in the registry to find AppVerifier's configuration.

Comment: maybe you activated appverfier to appverifier and this now triggers the crash?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I cleared out the registry key above. Bear in mind it also does this in three different machines :-(

Comment: I just installed Win10 1903 SDK and see the same on Win10 (1909). The GUI doesn't open, but on Windows 8.1, the GUI runs. so this is an Windows 10 issue

Comment: I just tested it on 1809 and here it also closes. On 1709 the application runs. so MS broke it in maybe one of the lastest Windows 10 monthly Updates

Comment: does my workaround also work for you? Or does it only work on my system?

Comment: I'm also unable to run app verifier too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562643/application-verifier-not-launching-on-microsoft-windows-10-pro

Comment: @vengy also try my [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563452/1466046) to run it as trustedinstaller

Comment: It does have a GUI. I use it all the time. After installing Windows update KB4577671 the GUI stopped displaying. This happened on 2 PCs. If you run appverif from VS you'll see it exit with a return code of 32. Using PsExec64.exe -i -s C:\Windows\System32\appverif.exe from the answer below works for me.

Comment: @rwebby there is now real solution available with an updated 2004 SDK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I managed to run the verifier under a SYSTEM account using PsExec:

...PsTools\PsExec64.exe -i -s C:\Windows\System32\appverif.exe

Comment: Works great! Thanks for this simple tip!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get "appverif exited on <desktop name> with error code -1073740940."

Comment: HOOOOLY! - I've run into exactly the same issue, and been postponing updating Windows since the last time I did (month or so ago), appverif was not working, but had to update today!. This is the bomb! Thank you!

Comment: Worked flawlessly form an elevated cmd. I'm wondering why this trick is needed in order to run the Application Verifier

Comment: @serg06 Ditto. Have you found a way to resolve this?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it (had to uninstall all WinSDKs, then re-install newest WinSDK)

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 19):

I asked Microsoft employee Gov Maharaj (from application compatibility team) and they already know about the issue and the issue is fixed in an update for the Windows 10 2004 SDK which was released in December 2020 (`19041.685.201201-2105.vb_release_svc_prod1_WindowsSDK.iso)`:

> The Windows 10 SDK, Version 2004 SDK servicing update (released
> 12/16/2020) contains the following fixes. If you encounter these
> issues, we recommend that you update your version of the SDK as soon
> as possible to avoid them:
>
> - **Resolved issue that prevented AppVerifier from working**

[Download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) and install the update to fix it.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot confirm this as Windows Defender detects trojans in the installer of ProcessHacker. Looks like they have this one sewn up, for now! :-(

Comment: never ever use defender on a dev system, it runs all unknown files in emulator which is slow and on dev system tons of files that defender hasn't seen are produced. And processhacker is safe to use

Comment: TendMicro also report ProcessHacker as Trojan or Chrome would not even let me download it. If you have a backchannel report this as false positive. It is really a shame or configure some exclusion directories if your scanner supports it.

Comment: @AloisKraus they follow Microsoft bullshit, they also had to block all sysinterals tools as they use same API like ProcessHacker and NOD32 is fine and doesn't block it

Comment: This worked for me! In the installer uncheck everything except "App Verifier", then once installation is finished, launch C:\Windows\System32\appverif.exe. Bam!

Comment: I had to uninstall all my WinSDKs (I had 2 versions installed) and [re-install the WinSDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/), but then it worked

Comment: Installing the new SDK version (without uninstalling the old version) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I downloaded the new SDK, ran the installed which downloaded the SDK installed and pointed me to a file that downloaded the SDK installer, which pointed me to a file that... you get the idea.
The installer did create a directory full of some individual installers though. None of these installed appverif.exe as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the recommended methods - installing the latest windows SDK and running the program through 'PsExec64.exe -i -s' but neither worked. This program seems to be something Microsoft periodically breaks, judging by what I've read.

I ran appverif.exe through visual studio and saw the following call stack on crash:

```
    ntdll.dll!RtlReportCriticalFailure()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpHeapHandleError()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpHpHeapHandleError()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpLogHeapFailure() Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal()    Unknown
```

> ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
> msvcrt.dll!00007ffd44449c9c()   Unknown
> appverifUI.dll!00007ffc9a41f9d6()   Unknown
> appverifUI.dll!00007ffc9a411636()   Unknown
> appverif.exe!00007ff64965281b() Unknown
> appverif.exe!00007ff6496615ed() Unknown
> kernel32.dll!00007ffd43957034() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown

It seems to be crashing after a heap free.